# Select everything and let with LINQ

Tags: linq

I want to select everything from a table and add a column `b` with `let`, like in this simplified example:

```
from a in Table
let b = 1
select new {a.ID, a.Title, a.Description, a.Name, b}
```

It works great, but I was wondering if there is an easier way then listing every single column I want to select. If I don't want the additional column, it's as easy as:

```
select a
```

In other words, is there something similar to `*` that I can use? Like:

```
select new {a.*, b}
```

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried just adding a `*` of course - No surprise that didn't work. Have also tried searching for the answer myself, but since everything I have found seems to point back to some similar solution to my first example, I'm guessing the answer to my question is *no*. But might as well ask anyway, before I stick with what I already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot do what you are trying to do. However, you could do this:

```
var items = from a in Table
            let b = 1
            select new { a, b }
```

This would allow you to not have to specify each individual property, as well as keeping your constant.

Comment: I actually tried this, but was a bit confused about the result as `a` becomes a column of objects separated from `b` (sorry if the terminology is wrong). But I can see how it has it's benefits. Big thanks!